# What I have is a list that was fetched from an api. Support me with react filter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What I have is a list that was fetched from an api. This list will be filtered based on the input. But at the first render it will render nothing, unless I press space or add anything to the input.

usinnng react when i click on the button it filters but I want at the first render to show the whole list before clicking

```
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function News() {
  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);
  const [listing, setLists] = useState([]);

  const fetchDataList = () => {
    return fetch("https://api.npoint.io/d275425a434e02acf2f7")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setLists(data.News);
       // data.News[0].id = 0;
        console.log(listing);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataList();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = () => {
    return fetch("https://api.npoint.io/91298d970c27e9a06518")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setNews(data.newsCategory);
        console.log(news);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const [filteredCat, setFiltredCat] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setFiltredCat(setLists());
  }, []);

  function filteredCategory(typecat) {
    let filteredCategory = listing.filter(
      (type) => type.categoryID === typecat
    );
    return filteredCategory;
  }
  function handleCategory(e) {
    let typeCategory = e.target.id

  typeCategory
      ? setFiltredCat(filteredCategory(typeCategory))
      : filteredCategory(setLists);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>Media</p>
      <h2>Top </h2>

      <div>
        {news &&
          news.map((idx) => (
            <Button id={idx.id} variant="secondary" onClick={handleCategory}>
              {idx.id} {idx.name}
            </Button>
          ))}
      </div>

      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            {filteredCat &&
              filteredCat.map((list) => (
                <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                  <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{list.title}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>{list.description}</Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="primary">{list.categoryID}</Button>
                  </Card.Body>
                </Card>
              ))}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default News;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the category as well when the data comes in,

Below your `setNews(data.newsCategory);` you can add `setFiltredCat(filteredCategory(news[0].id.toString()));`

edit:

To be sure the news has been set before setting your initial filter you could also add a hook which is watching for changes to `news`. Checkout [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-https-gshkxp?file=/src/App.js) for an example

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (news.length <= 0) return;

  setFiltredCat(filteredCategory(news[0].id.toString()));
}, [news]);
```

Edit: to return all listings initially you could use the same concept

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setFiltredCat(listing);
  }, [listing]);
```

Comment: Thanks , I just want to render the whole array as default not only the first item of the array

Comment: I edited the response to include rendering the whole array initially

Comment: do you know how to show cards as 3 coloums like this                                              
  [][][]                                             
  [][][]                                             
  [][][] searched alot and stuck in how to display them 3 col in each row

Comment: this is unrelated to your question. have a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and https://cssgridgarden.com/ and because you are using `react-bootstrap` check out https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/, but most of all use your "google skills". For example I just googled "react bootstrap 3 column layout"